# How do I write a SQL query involving a time stamp?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I write a SQL query involving a time stamp?

```
QUOTE_ID is a character string
CREATE_DTG is a date time type
RETENTION_LEAD_TRACK is a table
```

This sql statement

```
cmf.CommandText = "SELECT QUOTE_ID FROM RETENTION_LEAD_TRACK where CREATE_DTG > '2016 - 04 - 25 18:18:15.2891'"
```

throws this error
{"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."}

Comment: is this MySql or Sql Server?

Comment: This is sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `cmf.CommandText = "SELECT QUOTE_ID FROM RETENTION_LEAD_TRACK where CREATE_DTG > convert(datetime2,'2016 - 04 - 25 18:18:15.2891')"` thanks

Comment: Adding `CONVERT` isn't really a good solution here. As Brad observed, the problem is the spaces.

Comment: The spaces did not work.  I will have to add more to the OP to further explain the issue.

Comment: Actually, I think this is on the right track.  I mean, I think DONG has the right idea here

Comment: this modification has proven to be a success !!

Answer (score 2):

`2016 - 04 - 25` has spaces. Take those out

```
SELECT QUOTE_ID 
FROM RETENTION_LEAD_TRACK 
where CREATE_DTG > '2016-04-25 18:18:15.2891'
```

Comment: "yyyy - MM - dd HH:mm:ss.ffff" is what is in the SQL database and the sqlcommand is loaded like this:  cmf.CommandText = "SELECT QUOTE_ID FROM RETENTION_LEAD_TRACK where CREATE_DTG > " + "'" + currentDate.ToString("yyyy - MM - dd HH:mm:ss.ffff") +"'";

Comment: @xarzu Remove the spaces in your formatting string. They don't belong there. `yyyy-MM-dd` is the ISO date format.